# how to display menu of site in google results

Tags: google, seo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the most important things I need to do to encourage Google Sitelinks?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/503/what-are-the-most-important-things-i-need-to-do-to-encourage-google-sitelinks)

my site is first in google if you type '*עו"ד מימון כהן*' or '*maimon cohen lawyer*'.
I want to display menu index of the site in google, like this :
[image: ubuntu in google]

how to do it ?

Comment: Not a programming question.

Comment: The irony with this question is that if Dani-Br used Google's own search engine, the answer would be right near the top.

Answer (score 2):

The Google Webmaster Tools documentation for [Sitelinks](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=47334) explains how this feature works - note that it'll take a lot of work to establish your site as the top-ranked result *and* it'll take a relatively high search volume (i.e. people searching on "maimon cohen lawyer") for this feature to come into play.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can't do this over night, it's something controlled entire by google search. But you can start optimizing, and advertiging your site, submit it to ODP (dmoz.org). Then sing up for a google webmaster tools account and follow the reccomandations.

Then, in time if your site is well indexed google will add links to related pages in your site under the listing.