# How can I help Google build SiteLinks?

Tags: seo, sitelinks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the most important things I need to do to encourage Google Sitelinks?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/503/what-are-the-most-important-things-i-need-to-do-to-encourage-google-sitelinks)

I want to help Google build the `sitelinks`. Is there some HTML structure, css classes that I need to build to help it finding the relevant links?

How does Google build the `sitelinks`, is there a way I can help?

<sub>[SiteLinks example (w3schools)](http://www.google.com/search?sclient=psy&hl=en&site=webhp&source=hp&=&q=w3schools&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&pbx=1)</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Google has not released how they determine their sitelinks. However based upon their sitelinks support page it seems that the best practices for creating navigation links that become sitelinks is consistancy. Always using the same URL structure and anchor tags for each URL probably makes it easier for the algorithm to match important content to the URL it represents.

http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=47334