# How are Google Site links generated in search results?

Tags: google, pagerank, google-search, sitelinks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the most important things I need to do to encourage Google Sitelinks?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/503/what-are-the-most-important-things-i-need-to-do-to-encourage-google-sitelinks)

I just met a fellow designer who runs a website with the same pagerank as mine. When googling both our names, search results will show Site links below his website, but not mine. Do you know which attributes are handled by Google to define when and how these links are shown in search results?

Answer (score 7):

Here is a guide to using RDFa to get the most out of [Rich Snippets](http://knol.google.com/k/google-rich-snippets-tips-and-tricks#), however, it sounds as though you may be referring to [Site Links](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=47334) (please clarify if you are referring to neither).

Comment: Thanks, [danlefree](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/1064/danlefree). You were right, I was referring to Site Links instead. My bad, I'll correct my question right away. Do you still know the answer to the question above?

Comment: Ooops, I just found out some duplicate articles dealing with this issue.