# How to best format your HTML to help Google display your websites navigation with the search result for your site in Google Search?

Tags: html, google, navigation, google-search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the most important things I need to do to encourage Google Sitelinks?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/503/what-are-the-most-important-things-i-need-to-do-to-encourage-google-sitelinks)

Look at the first result for "smashing magazine" in the image below. See how Google grabbed SM's site navigation and displayed it below their search result? Are there any techniques that would help Google display the navigation like this? Are there any suggestions as to how to structure your HTML to help Google create this for your website's search result? Or in general, the best way to structure? Tricks of the trade? etc.?

[image: Smashing Magazine's navigation added to their search result in Google Search]