# Can I control the Google sitelinks for my website?

Tags: google, sitelinks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the most important things I need to do to encourage Google Sitelinks?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/503/what-are-the-most-important-things-i-need-to-do-to-encourage-google-sitelinks)

Working on SEO for a website, and i'm wondering if there's a way to have some say in which sub-links appear under the first entry when you google the website's name.  (i.e. when you google "amazon" there are 6 sub-links including "books", "music", "your account", etc. under the entry).

Currently if I google my site those 6 links include a couple of random pages as well as the Privacy Policy and Terms of Service which are only linked to in the footer, but several of the main sections of the site that are linked to in the top menu are left out.  (I say the pages it chooses are "random" because they don't correspond to the most-viewed based on google analytics, and I don't think special SEO-wise to make them stand out)

Is there a way to choose or at least influence what these sub-links will be?

Edit - What I call sub-links above are known as sitelinks (and are well documented in Google's Webmaster Tools, as Michael pointed out).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visit the [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/) section on sitelinks (under "Site Configuration"), which allows you to demote various sitelinks. This won't allow you to choose which sitelinks appear on your website, but it may decrease the likelihood that Google will select a particular page on your site as a sitelink.