# How to organize your site on google like amazon?

Tags: google, search-engine-indexing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the most important things I need to do to encourage Google Sitelinks?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/503/what-are-the-most-important-things-i-need-to-do-to-encourage-google-sitelinks)

I don't know the name of this feature neither how to search it on google.
But I would like my website to be shown like this:

http://jode.com.br/Joe/amazonongoogle.png

I have full access to the site and the tools of google to this site.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The are called google sitelinks - google creates with automated measures - you cannot add them to your site

http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=47334