# How to hide pages from Google crawler?

Tags: html, seo, search-engines

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the most important things I need to do to encourage Google Sitelinks?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/503/what-are-the-most-important-things-i-need-to-do-to-encourage-google-sitelinks)

I'm currently working on a website and need to keep certain pages hidden from Google crawler. How to make it so that search engines see only what I want them to see in a directory?

Also, you know how Google results also give you shortcut links, Like 'Login', 'About' etc... how to put these links to search result?

Comment: The questions pertaining to blocking Google's crawler can be found in many of the questions tagged "[robots.txt](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/robots.txt)"

Answer (score 1):

You can create a [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/) that disallows those locations.
Beware that not all crawlers will respect robots.txt.

Also, robots.txt is the first place an attacker will look.
You should protext those pages with a secure authentication system.

Answer (score 1):

[Robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `<meta name="robots" content="noindex,follow" />`

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like Google to not list certian URLs on your site, add them to [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/) in the root of your site.

```
Example robots.txt:
User-agent: *
Disallow: /donotindex/
```

Note that this is not secure, you're just "asking" Google to not index/list them.  Google will comply with this request.  However, sophisticated users and some poorly-behaved crawlers will use or list the URLs regardless.

If you need to hide the content you'll need to put it behind a login page (which crawlers can't use) or change your content based on the client (browser's) user-agent.  I believe the latter is specifically disallowed by Google and they may punish your site for doing go.