# How do we get our sites' sections displayed under the description in a Google search?

Tags: seo, google, google-analytics, search-engines, google-search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the most important things I need to do to encourage Google Sitelinks?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/503/what-are-the-most-important-things-i-need-to-do-to-encourage-google-sitelinks)

For Example, if I Google "Stack Overflow" the site comes up but also links to the main sections of the site right beneath it (Login, Questions, Careers...)

[image]

How can I achieve this with my own site?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment Google automatically includes this.

As Google Webmaster Tools explains

> Sitelinks are automatically generated links that may appear under your
>   site's search results."

This means you can't add them via some tool or code. The best you can do is to structure your correctly. See Google's page about this https://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=47334&hl=en