# How to get grid view presence in google search of my website as shown in google search for “twitter”?

Tags: seo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the most important things I need to do to encourage Google Sitelinks?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/503/what-are-the-most-important-things-i-need-to-do-to-encourage-google-sitelinks)

I have my website live and it is visible in google search but I want it to be displayed in a grid view as shown in google search of key word for example "twitter". Can someone guide me how to make this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google determines that, I have a website which got indexed like that in a few weeks. It's a WordPress site and I left off the trailing slash from the permalinks which were set to /%postname

The only advice I can give is to create a sitemap submit it and don't change your URL's

Comment: Can U ellaborate it?

Comment: There's nothing to really elaborate about. I redesigned a static site to use WordPress, I stripped the last slash just for personal preferences in the permalinks. The website has incoming links from some press it had received on examiner.com and a few morning talk shows on the West and East coast and that's about it. Google created those links. I forget the name of them but you can read about them in Webmaster Tools.