# How to make Google show my site in search result like the following image?

Tags: search, google, seo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the most important things I need to do to encourage Google Sitelinks?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/503/what-are-the-most-important-things-i-need-to-do-to-encourage-google-sitelinks)

Currently Google is displaying my site (http://layzend.info) like this in search result, only the link and meta description without any internal page links -

[image]

But I want to be the search result like the following where the internal links are also displayed -

[image]

How is it possible? Please help me to make my site more SEO friendly.

Answer (score 2):

They are called sitelinks. Google will decide if you have any.

Your only direct control is that you can remove them via Google Webmaster Tools.

How exactly Google decides what's worthy is unknown.

Answer (score 1):

These sitelinks will appear when your website gained enough authority.
The most li(n)ked pages will appear as sitelink.

If you want to have some special pages there, concentrate on linkbuilding for those!

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong but I do believe you have to setup a sitemap page and then tell Google to crawl that page so that your website is shown as the TeamViewer page.

Also, I suggest using the [Google Webmaster Tools](http://www.google.com/webmasters/).

[This link seems to be very useful too for quick and easy Sitemaps](http://www.xml-sitemaps.com/).