# How to add menu on google search result?

Tags: google-search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the most important things I need to do to encourage Google Sitelinks?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/503/what-are-the-most-important-things-i-need-to-do-to-encourage-google-sitelinks)

I want to ask how to make menu on google search result.E.g : when you search on google with keyword : Google community
and found www.stackoverflow.com, there are list of link below,those are 
Forums,Register Now,Members List,etc. How to make this menu in my website.

For example:

[image]

Comment: I added a screenshot of what I _think_ you're talking about to hopefully make the question clearer.

Comment: first use sitemaps..

Comment: i think i also need this case to be solved especially in wordpress. Anyway, how to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

You can not add or control that. This is made by google automatically. You can only define links which should never visible there.

Comment: how to define it become visible?