# Google Site Links

Tags: google, search-results

How can I get google sitelinks?

Comment: a link to the duplicate question is at the top of the page underneath the title of the question. If you can't see it, then the question is here: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/503/what-are-the-most-important-things-i-need-to-do-to-encourage-google-sitelinks