# Unique search engine results

Tags: search-engines

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the most important things I need to do to encourage Google Sitelinks?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/503/what-are-the-most-important-things-i-need-to-do-to-encourage-google-sitelinks)

[image: Search engine result]

How do i get those kind of result? With Categories below the main result. What is it called. i want to do as the picture. thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're called `SiteLinks` and are *automatically generated* by Google. Read more [[here]](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=47334)

You can increase the likelihood of having these created by "optimizing" your link structure, but it also depends on the number of visitors to your site I believe.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This type of search result comes when some one searches on Google with your site name specifically. Like in this case, you must have searched for "Zalora" or "Zalora.com", haven't you?

You can check it for other sites as well, say if you search for "my tablet guru" you will see similar result rolling out on the Google page.

Comment: Smart!!@!!!!!!!