# How to get Google to display a list of posts in the SERPs for a self hosted WordPress blog?

Tags: seo, wordpress, sitemap

My website is `javatechig.com` and is around 6 months old. I have used All-in-One SEO WordPress plugin for SEO tricks. Definitely after using SEO plugin, my website page view is increased, but still it is not giving one good site-link in Google Search.

I have followed the following steps:

1. Created *sitemap.xml* and submitted to Google Webmaster Tools
2. Edited all posts with meta tags
3. Header tags are carefully taken care

I want to make a sitelink similar to the attached image:

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the most important things I need to do to encourage Google Sitelinks?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/503/what-are-the-most-important-things-i-need-to-do-to-encourage-google-sitelinks)

Comment: Don't think sitelinks contain the date information, looks micro/schema date to me.

Answer (score 2):

Google only puts that particular display in the SERPs for forum sites that are hosted with common off the shelf forum software such as PHP-BB.    Google never displays blog sites like that, so you are out of luck.

Google seems to automatically detect the forum sites, and it puts this display in place for them.  There is nothing that a forum administrator can do to control it beyond choosing the forum software that powers their site.

That particular display in the SERPs is known as "forum sitelinks".  Here is Google's announcement about it (from 2009): http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2009/09/surfacing-forum-posts-in-search-results.html

Answer (score 1):

This is structured data at work, you need to take a look at the [Event Schema](http://schema.org/Event), you need to include this meta data in your site templates.

What this forum software must be doing is include the Event Schema details for every post that is posted.

Edited to add more references:

If you check the Event schema page, one method of highlighting this information is via JSON-LD script.

Another method to do this is via Google Webmaster Tools, to use the [Data Highlight tool](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2692911?hl=en).

You could check the syntax of your mark-up with the [Structured Data Testing tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/).

Comment: I found a few sites today that I used as code examples where these links occur. So far, I am seeing only forum sites showing up and none of them have event mark-up. If event mark-up works, then, *How?* Do you have examples? Can you add example code and/or references? Cn you explain this more? Cheers!!