# Are there other ways to manipulate the SERPs results aesthetics

Tags: seo, search-results

I have noticed that some forums are getting site links in the SERPs on desktop.

[image: screenshot of forum site links in Google SERPs]

When checking this URL in the [structured data testing tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/#url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.gardenersworld.com%2Fforum%2Fplants%2Fwhat-trees-can-be-planted-and-kept-in-pots%2F3656.html) there is no schema.

Has Google just plucked this information or are there other ways to display information in the SERPs?

Comment: Site links existed way before Schema.

Comment: These are not site links.   This is a special treatment for forum sites.

Comment: A list of all the ways that Google changes its search results will not fit in an answer here.

Comment: As for your question about how Google shows forum information see: [What causes Google to display a search result with a list of articles below](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/96617/what-causes-google-to-display-a-search-result-with-a-list-of-articles-below)

Answer (score 1):

first of all, there are open graph and html5. beside of this, Google is better and better in recognizing and structuring of information pieces, which are potentially structured through the kind, how they are built up, like forum threads, data tables and so on.

if you build something from scratch now, it would be a highly good idea to implement property/value, question/answer schema or structured lists to make it even easier for machines to understand dependencies