# Multiple site URLs now showing up in SERPs

Tags: google, google-search, search-results

Recently when you search for me on [Google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=scott+helme) several URLs from my blog have started showing up, instead of just the main URL.

1) https://scotthelme.co.uk/
2) https://scotthelme.co.uk/category/wifi-pineapple-2/‎
3) https://scotthelme.co.uk/wifi-pineapple-karma-sslstrip/

Is there a reason this starts happening? I have contemplated doing something to remove them but is it better to occupy the top 3 spots instead of just the top spot? Should I just leave them there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When Google shows multiple pages from your site, it is a sign that Google is confident that  when people are searching for you, your site is what they are looking for.   Google has determined that deep links into your site (such as your contact page, or your top articles) are likely to be more useful to searchers than links to other sites.

This means that your personal brand is growing and Google is recognizing it.  Google has given your site more real estate in the SERPs which is something that most webmasters strive for.   At some point Google may even use "site links" when somebody searches for you.  Site links shows your main URL, and then many sub-pages indented under it like this for a search for me:

[image: site links]

We have a very popular question here about [how to encourage Google to show site links for your website](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/503/what-are-the-most-important-things-i-need-to-do-to-encourage-google-sitelinks)

Answer (score 2):

You need to know Googlebot (Google web crawler) index all of the pages of your website it finds. That's why it can index multiple URLs of your website, it's just normal.

If I were you, I will leave these URLs in Google's index. Indeed, if you want to be found by others on Google, it's always better to occupy the most places you can in search results.