# Google shows "search instead for" when searching for our website

Tags: seo, google-search-console, search-engines, google-search

Our website is new and the name is similar (only one letter different than another website) completely different type and company though.

searching for xxxxxA works OK in Google and we find relatively good results.

However searching xxxxxA.com finds results for the other website and gives us the following options:

```
Showing results for xxxxxE.com
Search instead for xxxxxA.com (hyperlink when clicked then it is correctly searching for our site)
```

Questions:

1. Do we need to contact Google to correct this and if yes how ? if not will it be corrected
   automatically when the site becomes more popular and what is the process?
2. How do we make the process quicker?

Comment: Google deem the results they return to be the most relevant for a particular search query. They like to think that they know what the searcher is searching for better than them. There isn't anything you can do about this - when Google consider xxxxxA.com to have enough search volume, then this would automatically be changed so that it doesn't default to a search on xxxxxE.com which currently has more search volume.

Comment: It may be hard to accept but a popular site may well have more people mistyping a search than there are people searching for your site.  If that were the case then this behaviour might never be 'corrected' because it is already showing the best results for most people.  The only way for you to influence this is to legitimately increase the popularity of your site compared to theirs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is generally no way to contact Google about these types of issues.  This will get corrected automatically as your site becomes more popular.

This happened to me as well.  When I built some software and launched [a site](http://attesoro.org/), Google initially thought that the name I had chosen was a mis-spelling of something else.  By this point, Google has gone the opposite way and my site even [gets sitelinks](https://www.google.com/search?q=attesoro).  For me, it took nearly a year for Google to remove the "search instead for", but I didn't do much to try and speed up the process.  My site is also not very popular and even today, most of its Pagerank comes from my main site.

I suspect that the biggest signal that would indicate to Google that their "showing results for" is not appropriate, would be that people use the "search instead for" link.  I would ask friends and family to occasionally search for your site, click on "search instead for", and click through to your site (not more than once a week).

At the same time, work on building a quality site and promoting it.

We have a very popular post about [encouraging sitelinks](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/503/what-are-the-most-important-things-i-need-to-do-to-encourage-google-sitelinks) that might give you more ideas about what to work on.

Comment: I think you have got the way 'search instead for' appears back to front.  You want people to click on that to indicate that they searched for exactly what they meant.

Comment: Good point, updating my answer.

Comment: "This will get corrected automatically as your site becomes more popular." No, it won't. It remains as google thinks it should be. I wish there were a way to defeat this "feature". The alternate results are NEVER what I want. I'm careful with my searches and always mean to search what I type. I shouldn't have to ask to uncorrect my correct request.

Answer (score 3):

Google returns what it believes is the most relevant search results and this includes words that are often incorrectly spelt. From personal experience I can tell you it'll take some time to get Google to return `foo` instead of `boo`.

In order to get Google to return foo instead of boo you need to prove to Google that `foo` is `foo` and not anything else. *Many factors are involved when establishing a keyword on Google and these are what you can do:*

- Improve site authority.
- Gain organic back-links. (Anchor text foo) will help but key thing here is I said organic so don't go creating your own or if you do don't just use foo as the anchor text, Google uses link profiling on each site which involves link diversity (Platform Type/Follow Type/Link Type/Niche) and so on.. Which is very complex and often people who make there own links will fail.
- If a local or international business registering `foo` with many local citations sites will improve relevancy on the term `foo`.
- Time, there is no quick fix for this and its just something Google will kick in after you've shown that foo is not boo, patience is key here and of course the more people you have talking about your site the faster this process is... If your site doesn't offer anything new, or is a small local business it'll take some time but its still possible. If a local business `foo` may become `foo` quicker than say a international search since Google has set results for local and not local.

The other believed factor is when someone clicks show results for `foo` instead of `boo` this informs Google that `foo` is `foo` and will help towards gaining `foo` as the most revelant search.