# Will using page headings (h1, h2, h3 etc) as internal links encourage Google sitelinks?

Tags: seo, html, googlebot, sitelinks, heading

I am trying to change my site's page headings to better emphasize the structure of the page's content hierarchy. I am hoping this will encourage Google Sitelinks and list snippets.

Current headings are not optimized: I would like to use the `<h2>` heading as an internal link.

Will this encourage Google sitelinks and better content indexing?

```
<h2><a href="Example.com">text</a></h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've checked several sites that have site links.  None of the ones that I have checked use headline tags around the links that get chosen as site links.  Almost all the site links are chosen from navigation lists near the top of the page.

The only site that has a h1 link on the page that I checked was [CNN](http://www.cnn.com/).  They actually use a h1 tag for the title of the main story which is a link to read the full text of that story.  Google would be silly to choose it as a sitelink since it is so ephemeral.

For ideas that might actually work, see: [What are the most important things I need to do to encourage Google Sitelinks?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/503/what-are-the-most-important-things-i-need-to-do-to-encourage-google-sitelinks)