# Choose the Google Sitelinks that are shown when somebody searches for my website

Tags: google-search-console, google-search, sitelinks

How can I remove *Search for product*, *About us*, *Log in*, etc. which are displayed in Google Search?

And how can I add particular categories like *Automobiles*, *Mobiles & Tablets*, etc.?

[image]

Comment: Related: [What are the most important things I need to do to encourage Google Sitelinks?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/503/what-are-the-most-important-things-i-need-to-do-to-encourage-google-sitelinks)

Comment: Related: [How to remove a link from my sitelinks without removing it from indexing](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/142032/how-to-remove-a-link-from-my-sitelinks-without-removing-it-from-indexing)

Answer (score 4):

In order to remove particular categories in the Sitelinks result:

1. Go to your **Google Webmaster Tools** account
2. Click Sitelinks which is under **Search Appearance** section.
3. Give the link of your category that want to remove in `**Demote this sitelink URL:**` area

[image]

Likewise give all your links to remove from Sitelinks.

You can't add any particular categories manually to get that in Google Sitelinks results and Google automatically consider those links. In order to know more about how to get Sitelinks in Google see [What are the most important things I need to do to encourage Google Sitelinks?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/503/what-are-the-most-important-things-i-need-to-do-to-encourage-google-sitelinks).

Comment: As of 2016, [Google no longer allows webmasters to demote sitelinks](https://searchengineland.com/google-search-console-removes-sitelinks-demotion-feature-261002), thus this answer is outdated.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your Google Webmaster Tools account. On left navigation under *Search Appearance* click on *Sitelinks* and remove the links you don't want to appear under search results.

Sitelinks are automatically generated links that may appear under your site's search results. Learn more. If you don't want a page to appear as a sitelink, you can demote it. Only site owners and users with full permissions can demote sitelinks.

Comment: As of 2016, [Google no longer allows webmasters to demote sitelinks](https://searchengineland.com/google-search-console-removes-sitelinks-demotion-feature-261002), thus this answer is outdated.