# How to remove a link from my sitelinks without removing it from indexing

Tags: seo, google-search-console, sitelinks, google-sitelinks-searchbox

I have this shop website which contains a lot of dynamic product. I added a dynamic sitemap which updates constantly. it did great to my SEO and click rates but now its adding the products on the sitelinks(these nested links below my site's links). how can I remove them from sitelinks without removing them from indexing. I want them to appear as a separate link instead of nested indented links of the main search result.

[image]

Comment: Related: [What are the most important things I need to do to encourage Google Sitelinks?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/503/what-are-the-most-important-things-i-need-to-do-to-encourage-google-sitelinks)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the NOSNIPPET meta tag:

```
<meta name=”robots” content=”nosnippet”>
```

I talk a bit more about it [here](https://www.andreguelmann.com/blog/prevent-page-from-appearing-as-sitelink-on-google/)