# From where does Google gets these links

Tags: seo, google, google-search, search

I'm just about to optimize a website. Now I would like to know from where Google obtains these links:

[image: screenshot]
Why? I also want some links to appear on the search-result for my homepage

Comment: There are [sitelinks](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/503/what-are-the-most-important-things-i-need-to-do-to-encourage-google-sitelinks).

Comment: Almost but not quite sitelinks. They're breadcrumb links which you can use microformat markup to tell Google about so Google will display them in your search results.