# Bing "Search within" Bar in Results

Tags: bing, site-search

Bing has started showing a "Search within xyz.com" bar for some searches. This appears in the organic listings and not ads (like Google has).

[image: Bing Search Bar]

This has recently started showing for one of my clients but lands on the wrong page internally when used. I've searched for instructions on how to control this but to no avail.

How can we make sure users end up landing on a page of results for the search terms entered into this box?

How can we get this to appear for other clients' sites?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't much you can do about this type of feature for any search engine.   If the results are directing to the wrong page when using the feature, it is a bug at Bing and not something that you will be able to fix.

As for how to encourage Bing to show this feature, it should be the same as the advice for [What are the most important things I need to do to encourage Google Sitelinks?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/503/what-are-the-most-important-things-i-need-to-do-to-encourage-google-sitelinks):

- Use regular links rather than JavaScript throughout your site
- Give it time
- Put text links in your footer