# SEO for Google: navigation, company info, video

Tags: seo, google, sitemap, video, navigation

I often stumble upon search results in Google that get a special treatment, like:

- having the site navigation (and more) being displayed on the search results page
  [image: Navigation, Location, Review, and special search]
- having a company's location, contact information, Google reviews and e.g. opening hours being displayed aside the search results
  [image: location, contact information, reviews, etc.]
- having a video thumbnail being displayed with the search result and the navigation structure being displayed instead of the blank URL (`giga.de` > Deals)
  [image: video thumbnail and navigation instead of url]

I'm building a website for my (nationally pretty well known) choir but have not been into search engine optimization, yet. There's many blogs and documents on that topic. But what I want is that special behavior described above. Can you tell me how I can reach that? Or are there any documents that deal with these (and more?) special Google features?

Comment: @John Conde Question is not only about Sitelinks but also about Local Businesses Data Highlighter, Video mark up and site hierarchy display. Then how it would be a duplicate of http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/503/what-are-the-most-important-things-i-need-to-do-to-encourage-google-sitelinks alone?

Comment: It is actually too broad but at least this way one of their questions is answered.

Comment: @JohnConde Yes, Actually I flagged this question as 'Too broad' only but I tried to answer for OP. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your first question is about Sitelinks. Google [says](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=en) that this
   process is entirely automated and see [this](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/503/what-are-the-most-important-things-i-need-to-do-to-encourage-google-sitelinks) question for more
   information about Sitelinks.
2. Second one is about [Data Highlighter - Local Businesses](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/3106959?hl=en)

   > You can use Data Highlighter to tag data about your business, such as
   >   its name, address, customer reviews, and ratings. Then Google can
   >   present your data more attractively -- and in new ways -- in search
   >   results and in other products.

   You can tag data about your business using [this](https://www.google.com/local/business/add) URL.
3. You have to mark up your videos with `schema.org` to show that video
   thumbnail in Google results.

   > When video content is marked up in the body of the page, search
   >   engines and other sites can recognize it and may use it to improve the
   >   display of video content on a page or in search results. Marking up
   >   your content provides information about your videos that allows Google
   >   and other sites to index them

   See [this](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/156442?hl=en) link.
4. News from [seroundtable](http://www.seroundtable.com/archives/021182.html) says

   > Google announced that when a URL is too long, they might now replace
   >   the URL in the Google search results with a "site hierarchy display,"
   >   or what appears to look more like a breadcrumb trail. Technically,
   >   Google analyzes a site's breadcrumb trail and shows this instead for a
   >   "small percentage of search results."

   See the [news](http://googleblog.blogspot.in/2009/11/new-site-hierarchies-display-in-search.html) from Google's official blog.

Comment: Thanks for the links. Except for the site links, I'm also interested in having my location being shown with the search result, and even an option for searching only my site with google, just as in the Microsoft example. Can you help me with that, as well? =)