# How to show my links in structured way like Amazon do

Tags: google-search

Can you please tell me how links like `Books` `EC2` appear in search results associated with Amazon.com? How can I do similar with my site's main section?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking about sitelinks. Sitelinks are automated. Google [says](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=en) that they only show sitelinks if they think they will be useful for users.

> We only show sitelinks for results when we think they'll be useful to
>   the user. If the structure of your site doesn't allow our algorithms
>   to find good sitelinks, or we don't think that the sitelinks for your
>   site are relevant for the user's query, we won't show them.

In order to increase the possibility to show your website's sitelinks, you need to improve the quality of your website.

> For example, for your site's internal links, make sure you use anchor
>   text and alt text that's informative, compact, and avoids repetition.

You can find more answers for your question [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/503/what-are-the-most-important-things-i-need-to-do-to-encourage-google-sitelinks).

Answer (score 0):

Those are called sites links, they are automatically generated by the algorithm. You will get site links once you site is "strong" enough in Google's view. Google will not tell you what site links you have but you can choose to demote site links (once you find out the ones you have - apart for the obvious ones to the homepage) using webmaster tools.