# Google sitelinks appearing when our brand name is searched with a space but not appearing when searched without the space

Tags: google-search, sitelinks

When we search Google for *word1 word2*, it lists our site at #1 with 4 or 5 sitelinks underneath which is what we wanted.

Question - is there anything we can do to help achieve the same result/layout for the search *word1word2* which also appears at #1 but without the sitelinks?

Our brand name is word1word2(all one word) and we never split the words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Google decides in which cases your site has sitelinks and which cases has not.

And it's most probably Google sees word1word2 as two separate words even if it's your brand name. In a domain name, keywords are necessarily sticked; that's why Google tries to separate keywords to show up your site in SERPs when it's relevant (in relation to search terms).

You can try to [encourage Google sitelinks](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/503/what-are-the-most-important-things-i-need-to-do-to-encourage-google-sitelinks) but in your case I'm not sure it will work.