# Why doesn't Google show full site links for my site in some countries?

Tags: seo, google, wordpress

I would like Google to show descriptions for each site link for my website (WordPress) when searching the word 'esika' in Google.

The website is from Peru and searching 'esika' from google.com.pe shows the official website first position.  However, the sublinks are small without description. The same is true when searching in other countries like Chile, Ecuador

[image: From Peru]

If I search the same thing 'esika' with Google Spain (google.es), I get the official website first position but with the categories with their descriptions. The same happens with lots of other countries like Canada, Venezuela, Ecuador, and France.

[image: From Spain]

What is the difference between these countries? How can I get Google Peru to show those descriptions?

Comment: Simple, you can't unless you provide alternative or multiple language support on your website.. No one wants to see a website fill up 35% or more of their screen in a lang they can't read. If your site was international english you'd see those results in all english countries, i.e CA, US, UK and so on, you wouldn't get them .fr Google.

Comment: But the site is in spanish and in the peruvian version of google doesn't show up, but in Venezuela who also speaks spanish the description is shown. In my header I have `<meta property="og:locale" content="es_es">`

Comment: As far as I know Open Graph meta tags are only used by Google Plus, Facebook and other social networking platforms. You should be using [hreflang="x-default"](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en) or `vz_ES`  Also in webmaster tools ensure your website is not GEO targetting. It needs to be unlisted see: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/62399?hl=en

Comment: I was reading about hreflang as you suggested, so to understand it... I only have one language in the website, should I put `<link rel=”alternate” hreflang=”es-pe” href=”http://esika.biz” />` ? The thing is that the website is for Peru and it is in Google Peru where I can't see the descriptions

Comment: See also: [What are the most important things I need to do to encourage Google Sitelinks?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/503/what-are-the-most-important-things-i-need-to-do-to-encourage-google-sitelinks) which doesn't explain why Google might be doing things differently in different countries, but does explain how Google chooses whether or not to show site links.

Comment: I think it's related to your website popularity issue. It has to come down to popularity and the keywords.

Answer (score 1):

It has to come down to popularity and the keywords.

If people are not interested in your site, then google won't give much interest into it either.

Also, your keyword is "esika". Use various keyword density tools on the internet and check to see that "esika" takes up 2% to 4% of all keywords on a single webpage. If the percentage is too low then search engines will think that word is not important. If the percentage is too high, then search engines will think you're trying to make that keyword #1 in an artificial way (like in a spammy way). Try to include a few more keywords with the same density so that search engines will index you for more reasons than one.

It is also possible that some versions of google are outdated because the google team assigned to a particular country might not have the skills and/or time to update the script that produces the results pages.

One more thing. Make a sitemap for every page to your website and submit it into google webmaster tools to make sure they understand your entire website and then fix any errors it finds. That will increase your chances of having bigger results that you are aiming for.

If you tried everything, then you may want to try to contact the people of google to see their progress on updating the google results. Things change nearly all the time with google.

Other than that, give at least 48 hours for google to update their search results database and do your search again.