# Sitelinks showed for both search keys: with and without space

Tags: seo, google-search, search-results, sitelinks

I noticed that, for some sites, if I look for i.e.: "benny ben", I don't see Sitelinks, instead if I look for "bennyben" *(which matches with the domain name)* then I see them. How can I make Google showing Sitelinks for both searches?

Comment: Please limit your post to one question.     That also would allow you to differentiate the title of the post from the older question.

Comment: Ok @StephenOstermiller can I modify it or do I have to delete it and open another one?

Comment: You can modify this one and I will re-open it.  You can ask additional questions as new posts.

Comment: I think this particular question is answered by [What are the most important things I need to do to encourage Google Sitelinks?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/503/what-are-the-most-important-things-i-need-to-do-to-encourage-google-sitelinks).   Particularly [mvark's answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/1154/14543) where it says that the query has to refer only to your site with a high probability.

Answer (score 0):

Sitelinks normally are those pages that have more traffic than other pages of that particular website and have better structure. Keep your most hot content for which you want to rank and appear as Site Link, put them in menu bar for example, if you want sitelink of a page focusing on iPhone XS, put link of iPhone XS category (or post/article) in start of navigation menu. This will put it at first of site links in Google.