# What is this section called in Google Search?

Tags: google-search, search-results

I want to have something like this for my website:

[image]

What is this called?

Comment: It's call Sitelinks. You can tweak it in the search console.

Comment: [What are the most important things I need to do to encourage Google Sitelinks?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/503/17633)

Comment: @DominiqueH - You used to be able to tweak it in Google Search Console. Google removed that functionality. https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking at is sitelinks. Specifically, in your screenshot, these are paid search sitelinks. There are also organic search sitelinks. In the screenshot, the top result is DigitalOcean's paid search ad, which appeared because you searched for their brand name, and underneath is their organic result.

[Paid search sitelinks](https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/2375416?hl=en) are Google Ads ad extensions. When you create an Expanded Text Ad, you have the option of including various extensions, and the sitelink extension is the one that supports deep linking to your site's various pages and appears in your screenshot. You point out the pages you want to display. Your ad has to be in first position to display these in Google, so it has to decisively win the auction. Also, Google will decide, based on many different factors of relevance and clickthrough history, how many sitelinks will show (anywhere from 2 to 8).

[Organic sitelinks](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=en) are likewise deep link pages, but you have less control over what shows up. You can't explicitly tell Google what to display there (though you can optimize your pages in a way you think might help). Google will select which pages to deep link to, if any at all. You also have to be at the top of the SERP for the query. Google will then decide if your sitelinks might be relevant.

Comment: thanks you henry , now i will research more