# Google showing site links only for USA

Tags: seo, geotargeting, sitelinks

Google is showing my websites' sitelinks only to the USA (I can only see the sitelinks via VPN) i already added my country on google search console international targeting. how can i fix this?

Comment: There isn't a lot you can do to control sitelinks.  See [What are the most important things I need to do to encourage Google Sitelinks?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/503/what-are-the-most-important-things-i-need-to-do-to-encourage-google-sitelinks)   I doubt that you will get an answer that is different from those posted there, but I'll leave this question open (not duplicate) because the other question doesn't mention anything about them only appearing in certain countries.

Comment: but why is it showing in USA?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, as Stephen mentioned above, there isn't that much you can do to make Google display sitelinks in organic search results. Per [Google's own documentation](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=en), "We only show sitelinks for results when we think they'll be useful to the user. If the structure of your site doesn't allow our algorithms to find good sitelinks, or we don't think that the sitelinks for your site are relevant for the user's query, we won't show them."

Basically, if Google shows sitelinks in the US but not elsewhere, it means Google deems your deep site content to be more useful for searchers in the US. There are a few things you can do, in addition to what was already mentioned in Stephen's link to a previous response, but again, this doesn't guarantee anything; it might improve the chances.

1. Analyze the search trends from different countries. You can use Google Search Console, Google Analytics (or whatever analytics program you have installed), and any other service you may be using (like Moz or Ahrefs) to look at search queries that bring users to your site, broken down by region. Then examine their behavior on the website, their site search queries, etc. Look for differences in US vs other country trends, and pivot your content strategy based on that.
2. Have you implemented hreflang meta tags? If not, and your website is available in different languages and regional variations, you may wish to do this. Here's [the Yoast guide](https://yoast.com/hreflang-ultimate-guide/); see if this applies to you, and if you have it implemented properly.
3. Do you have [structured data](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data) properly implemented on your website? It can help search engines understand what the website is about. If the data is in English, for example, but you have different language versions (per #2 above), you may consider structured data that matches the language of the website.

Again, these are general good practices and they may work, but there's still no guarantee.