# How should I label combined image/text links so Google will choose them for sitelinks?

Tags: seo, sitelinks

The homepage of my ecommerce ticketing site has links to events with tickets for sale. They consist of an image as well as text describing the event and the price of the ticket, like this:
[image: Image link example]

I'd like to get these links to show up as Sitelinks on the search engine results page for my brand. I implemented them as a single anchor tag that wraps both the image and the three text divs. Is that too much information for a search engine crawler to understand this link?

I have seen guides for optimizing [image links](https://www.searchenginejournal.com/internal-image-links-seo/196007/) and [text links](https://www.mediavine.com/what-is-anchor-text-seo-best-practices-for-links/), but I haven't seen anything for compound image / text links like these. Should I split it into two links to the same page, one text and one image, or would that be worse?

Comment: I have never seen sitelinks results including images as the links so I would suggest using separate href's.

Comment: See also: [What are the most important things I need to do to encourage Google Sitelinks?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/503/what-are-the-most-important-things-i-need-to-do-to-encourage-google-sitelinks)

Answer (score 2):

There is no way that you can instruct Google to show sitelinks on your search engine organic results or on search ads. You can only work on backend effectively to expect sitelink extensions.

There are three types of sitelink extensions-

1.) · Sitelink extensions with links

2.) · Sitelink extensions with description of links

3.) · Sitelink extensions with links and images aka visual sitelinks

You can create sitelinks and enable for your brand on Google AdWords. To make sure that get a sitelink associated your results, you need have:

1.) · Less text on links

2.) · Links that reflect your site

3.) · Link descriptions

4.) · Images with links