# Limit Google site links to just my subdomain when currently they include other sites that don't belong to me from the same domain

Tags: seo, google-search, sitelinks

I've been struggling to find some information about sitelinks that Google generates when I search for the webapp I'm working on.
[image]

As you can see in the image, I'm working on this website `vitrine.globo.com`, which is a subdomain of `globo.com`. The problem is that it generates these sitelinks that have nothing to do with the page.

It's a simple Angular application and I've added all required meta tags and information for SEO, but none of them seems to be related with sitelinks.

Is there a way to do this? A few links i've found says that this behaviour is automated, so it means we can't have any control about it?

Comment: You're correct in that it's [automated](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=en). Since I don't know the search term you're using, I'm guessing the sitelinks are coming from the root domain (`globo.com`) or another subdomain. If you don't have any control over these and can't block the indexing of those URLs that are appearing in the sitelinks, then you have limited choices:  move your site to a different domain instead of a subdomain, or try to encourage Google to use different sitelinks...

Comment: See:  [What are the most important things I need to do to encourage Google Sitelinks?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/503/what-are-the-most-important-things-i-need-to-do-to-encourage-google-sitelinks) for the later.

Comment: Could you buy your own domain name and move your site rather than using a subdomain of some other site?   Or are you somehow tied to that subdomain?