# How can we hide the Google Review Button and show other buttons instead?

Tags: seo, search-results, user-reviews

We wanted to hide the Google Review button and add overview & course admission buttons. For example:

If you see [our Google Page](https://www.google.com/search?q=shikshapeeth%20college%20of%20management%20and%20technology&sxsrf=ALiCzsbrUuEOg1LcaqWyNjyPRBnuCSfwXw%3A1655813718403&source=hp&ei=VraxYuLRFpn4-QaHjIGADw&iflsig=AJiK0e8AAAAAYrHEZlAyASjwfIaSzsfAk4PeOJzlg4H4&gs_ssp=eJwNyDEOwjAMAECxwie8MNdWXavuE_hF5LgOIk2QmgF-Dzfe9TbFRGO3YEG8bHf8zIoZWZ2VbF0lb_8i00yiLLJkJnzQWZ6vs6S3-yhgvVYPh77DkVoKP7wNSC3DcCut1x7fH_38IJs&oq=shik&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMYADIKCC4QxwEQrwEQJzIECCMQJzIECCMQJzIFCAAQkQIyCggAELEDEIMBEEMyCAguEIAEELEDMgQIABBDMgsILhCABBCxAxDUAjIECAAQQzIFCC4QgAQ6BwguENQCEEM6BAguEEM6BQgAEIAEOgsIABCABBCxAxCDAToRCC4QgAQQsQMQgwEQxwEQ0QM6BwguELEDEEM6CwguEIAEELEDEIMBOgsIABCABBCxAxCLAzoLCC4QgAQQsQMQiwM6CwgAELEDEIMBEIsDUABY7wJglAloAHAAeACAAcgBiAGcBZIBBTAuMy4xmAEAoAEBuAEC&sclient=gws-wiz), the review button is coming on top.

But if you see [any other Google Review Page](https://www.google.com/search?q=meri%20college&sxsrf=ALiCzsbTwfpAWJ0XxgsOGzeoVYRUT6RTKQ%3A1655813277835&source=hp&ei=nbSxYsGUMYHh-AbDnZ-ABg&iflsig=AJiK0e8AAAAAYrHCrTPAicKCUAH9ufdho0w688HHIUwL&gs_ssp=eJzj4tVP1zc0zDAySYnPM7IwYPTiyU0tylRIzs_JSU1PBQB5sgjX&oq=meri&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMYADIECC4QJzIKCC4QxwEQrwEQQzIECC4QQzIHCAAQQxCLAzIHCAAQQxCLAzIHCAAQQxCLAzIHCAAQQxCLAzIHCAAQQxCLAzILCAAQgAQQsQMQiwMyCwgAELEDEIMBEIsDOgQIIxAnOgQIABBDOgcILhDUAhBDOgsILhDHARCvARCRAlAAWNICYJoJaABwAHgAgAHqAYgBhgaSAQUwLjMuMZgBAKABAbgBAw&sclient=gws-wiz), there is no Review button. Also, there are two more buttons i.e. overview & course admission.

[image]

How can we do changes as per the above mentioned link in our Google Business Page?

Comment: I don't see a "review" button (or any buttons at all) for your school.  The search results may vary by user or by location.  I do see the "Overview" and "Course admissions" buttons for the other school, so I added a screen shot.

Comment: I'm not sure if Google is doing something different for these buttons compared to sitelinks, but this question is related: [What are the most important things I need to do to encourage Google Sitelinks?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/503/what-are-the-most-important-things-i-need-to-do-to-encourage-google-sitelinks)

Comment: I don't see it either.  Maybe it's popping up only for you.

Comment: Hi Rohit & Stephen, Sorry i captured screenshot from Laptop But i was meant for Mobile Version. Please refer Mobile Screenshot. Type Shikshapeeth College and you will see there is 4 buttons overview, photos, Reviews & about. So, we wanted to hide Review button. Sorry I am not able to add attachment..

Comment: Also, Please refer other college (Meri College) in Mobile version, you will be able to see that there is only two buttons Overview & Course admission.