# Website search results sub pages show incorrect content

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-search

I'm helping a small business with their SEO and one of the things we noticed is when you search for their website specifically the suggested sub pages (I'm not sure what this is technically called) aren't displaying the correct meta description. It's displaying content in the footer for some reason.

If I search for the page specifically on Google the meta description will display correctly.

Here's an example of what I mean:

[image: image of stack exchange search result]

In this case "Math", "French Language", "Sites", etc., are all what I mean when I say 'sub pages'. And the text beneath the links is not showing the copy I would like it to. Is there a way to tell Google what text to display with these links?

Comment: Those are called "sitelinks."  I don't think this answers your question but it is related: [What are the most important things I need to do to encourage Google Sitelinks?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/503/what-are-the-most-important-things-i-need-to-do-to-encourage-google-sitelinks)