# Google sitelinks directing to old website

Tags: seo, google, search, sitelinks

We have launched a new website last Dec but till now the sitelinks are still directing to some of the old site pages (subdomain) which have the same domain as the new site. We submitted a sitemap to Google Search Console to crawl but it didnt seem to help this.

Appreciate if anyone could advise how we can influence how the sitelinks are chosen

Comment: More information please.  Pick one page and show us the urls and the headers

Comment: Have you redirected those URLs to their equivalent at the new site?

Comment: Related: [What are the most important things I need to do to encourage Google Sitelinks?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/503/what-are-the-most-important-things-i-need-to-do-to-encourage-google-sitelinks)

Comment: here is the url to the new site: https://www.turfclub.com.sg/en.html
and the sitelinks are: https://racing.turfclub.com.sg/en/race-cards/
https://racing.turfclub.com.sg/en/race-results/
https://racing.turfclub.com.sg/en/race-videos/
https://racing.turfclub.com.sg/en/home-page/

Comment: For those particular sitelinks, we dont have the equivalent pages on the new site

Answer (score 1):

Google will show the sitelinks they find suitable to visitors based on your internal linking structure. The update/removal is not automatic.

1. Check if you keep old links on the new website.
2. Define what would be your desired sitelinks now, and make sure that all the other pages link to those.
3. Create redirections to make sure the whoever finds an old link will be landing on teh new site. If you have no page close to the old content, take them to the new home.
4. Submit the site agaign using Search Console.

There are many similar questions related to "[sitelinks](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=sitelinks)", you may want to check them out to find other responses and tips.